# Quarkus: native container missing GLIBC_2.32

Tags: docker, quarkus, graalvm-native-image

I just started a new Quarkus (v2.1) project, created with the integrated generator in IntelliJ. The project is pretty much empty but i can't get the native docker container working. Doesn't matter if I build it with GraalVM on the host or inside another container I always get this error if I try to run the container:

```
./application: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by ./application)
```

My environment:
*Pop!_OS 21.04,
GraalVM 21.2.0,
Docker  20.10.7*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `-Dquarkus.native.container-build=true` in order to make Quarkus use a container when creating the native binary, instead of relying on a local GraalVM installation

Comment: Thank you, now i feel stupid. I thought I already tried this but had a typo in this maven option.

Comment: No worries, happens to everyone :)